# Create a blank profile when user signs up

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I know this question has been asked on here once before but I need to know if parse has done anything about it.
My default user table has a pointer field to a UserProfile class.
On signup I have this cloud code below.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User,async (request)=>{
      const user = request.object;
     //Making a new Teacherprofile Class
     const Objectextension = Parse.Object.extend("TeacherProfile");
     const teacherProfile = new Objectextension();
     teacherProfile.set("name", "harry");
     //Putting teacher profile pointer
     user.set("tProfile",teacherProfile);
    });
```

This just dosent not work and results in a timeout.Is there anyway to create the userprofile on before save and associate it to the User Table ? Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is the working code.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User,async (request)=>{
      const user = request.object;

      //if user id does not exists
      //it is a new user
      if (!user.id) {
        //Making a new User Profile Object
        const profileObject = Parse.Object.extend("TeacherProfile");
        const teacherProfile = new profileObject();
        teacherProfile.set("name", "harry");
        await teacherProfile.save(null,{ useMasterKey: true });
        //Putting teacher profile pointer in user
        user.set("tProfile",teacherProfile);
      }else{
        console.log('old user');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any beforeSave or afterSave trigger for 'TeacherProfile' ?

Comment: No other handler, but it seems as if there was a scheme miss Match for the pointer in user and for that reason I think it went into a loop, now its completely fine :D
Thanks for you comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more of experimentation I have come to the conclusion that before save is not at all advisable for User Profile Creation. 
When signing up lets say the username or email already exists , then the signup does not happen but the profile is saved regardlesss.
So I would advice against it

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, (request) => {

  if(!request.original){
    //Object saved for first time. This codes will work just first time. And will not work after object saved again.
    const user = request.object;

    const profileObject = Parse.Object.extend("TeacherProfile");
    const teacherProfile = new profileObject();
    teacherProfile.set("name", "harry");
    await teacherProfile.save(null,{ useMasterKey: true });
    //Putting teacher profile pointer in user
    user.set("tProfile",teacherProfile);
    user.save(null,{useMasterKey:true});

  }

});
```

Comment: No you cannot use that code , you will cause a horrible loop effect where this code will keep on running for infinity since you are saving your user class in the afterSave handler of user class.

Comment: @TanzimChowdhury thats why I used if(!request.original){ }

Comment: Like I said it won't work, i had restrictive logic in my code too but sadly it goes into a recursive loop